# Display a javascript popup on page load using XSL

Tags: javascript, xslt

I want to display a popup when the page load completes. I am using XSL and javascript for this. But I do not know why the popup does not display when the page loads.

My code:

```
function alkesh(){
    alert("Alkesh called");
    var isQuotedPriceChanged = <xsl:value-of select="wtransactionGeneralData/isQuotedPriceChanged"/>;

    alert("IsQuotedPriceChanged value is ["+isQuotedPriceChanged+"]");
    if(isQuotedPriceChanged=="Y"){
        alert("Your requested price was adjusted by spreading calculation");
    }
```

Javascript is at the end of the same XSL file. This is my call to the javascript function:

```
<script>
    window.onload=alkesh;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var isQuotedPriceChanged = <xsl:value-of select="wtransactionGeneralData/isQuotedPriceChanged"/>;` to `var isQuotedPriceChanged = '<xsl:value-of select="wtransactionGeneralData/isQuotedPriceChanged"/>';`.

Comment: Hi Martin , but my problem is here that window.onload is not working . My page does not load fully and javascript not called. Can you please suggest any other way to call javascript method on complete page load

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem. Your current snippet tries to create Javascript code with XSLT where I simply think the script has a syntax error, that way your code can't be called at all, whether onload or elsewhere. So check the error console F12 of your browser for any script errors and fix them.